# Deleting an edge between two vertices [igraph python]

Tags: python, igraph

I can't believe I'm having a hard time with this, but here we are... This should be straight forward, here's my code:

```
i = random.choice(ER.vs)
j = random.choice(ER.vs)

if t < 1:
    ER.add_edge(i,j)
else:
    ER.delete_edges(ER.get_eid(i.index,j.index))
```

The last line doesn't work. I've tried different ways to delete the edge between i and j, but I can't seem to figure out the function. Could anyone help?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it works with igraph0.6:

```
import random
import igraph

N = 10
g = igraph.Graph.Full(N)
i, j = random.sample(range(g.vcount()), 2)
g.delete_edges([(i,j)])
print(g.ecount(), N*(N-1)/2)
```

From the output can be concluded, it has deleted one edge:

```
44 45.0
```

Comment: Oh I see, you go get vertices ids directly (random.sample(range(g.vcount()), 2)) instead of the actual nodes (random.choice(ER.vs)). That should work indeed! Thanks!